# Printing IP address of Nic card to bash using script

Tags: linux, fedora

currently I am working on a school assignment on Linux using Vim where I have to write a script that displays the user that is currently logged in, the time and date, and list only the IP address of the Nic card. I have everything working except for the IP address part. If anyone could help I would appreciate it greatly.

Edit to include the code I have at the moment.

```
#!/bin/bash
Time=$(date)
IP=$(ifconfig ens33)
echo "The following user is currently logged in $USER"
echo ""
echo "The current time is $Time"
echo ""
echo "The IP information is $IP"
```

Comment: Sorry, we won't write the code for you. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the result of `ifconfig` using `awk` like this (IPv4):

```
$ ifconfig ens33 | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2, 6)}'
```

Result:

> 10.10.xx.xx

`inet addr:` represents IPv4 address.
`inet6 addr:` represents IPv6 address.

Comment: @Lilcomet: Did it help?

Comment: Yes it worked awesome. I have another thread with another question about using "find" in a script is could you give me any advice?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332967/how-would-i-implement-the-search-function-to-find-a-file-or-directory

Comment: @Lilcomet: That's great. :) Sure, I'll take a look at it. You need to accept an answer to conclude this question.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
IP=$(ifconfig ens33| grep inet | sed 's/ */ /'  | cut -d" " -f3)
```