# How would I implement the search function to find a file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

I am currently working on a script for bash that will ask the user for a starting location and a file name then search for the file. If possible I would also like to cat the file once found. Here is the script I have so far if someone would point out how I would include the function I would be very thankful. Also still a Unix beginner so please bear with me :)

```
#!/bin/bash
function press_enter
{
    echo""
    echo -n "Press Enter to continue"
    read
    clear
}
selction=
until [ "$selection" = "3" ]; do
echo -e "Where would you like to search
1- Root
2- Home
3- Exit

Enter your choice ---> \c"
read selection
case $selection in
    1) cd / ; press_enter ;;
    2) cd /home ; press_enter ;;
    3) echo "Have a nice day!" ; exit ;;
esac
done
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `find`?

Comment: I have not had to much practice with the find command outside of using it in Bash to search for a file. I'm just not sure how I would use it in the script I am writing.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/find.1.html) as one command, or use your selection inputs to drive `find` in your script.

```
find $where_selection -name $what_selection
# with cat:
find $where_selection -name $what_selection -exec cat {} \;
```

`-exec cat {}` replaces the `{}` with the current found file path from `find`.

Comment: Awesome that seems a lot simpler than what I was making it out to be through reading and what not. But one last part I am getting hung up on is how do I get the user input as in the file they are looking for? So I can call upon the input when using find.

Comment: I think you were on the right track, you just need to read another variable.
`read where_selection; read what_selection; echo "find $where_selection -name $what_selection"`